# Tengo una consulta sql, quiero saber como puedo imprimirlo con php

Tags: php, mysql

Esa es mi consulta de Mysql:

```
SELECT SUM(Cantidad) as total FROM ficha
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
 <?php 
    $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','database');

     $sql="SELECT SUM(Cantidad) as total FROM ficha";
     $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
     echo $result;

   ?>
```

Comment: Imprimirlo en una tabla o como?, no queda claro que resultado esperas obtener

Comment: Solo el puro resultado y si es en una tabla estaría bien tmb.

Comment: ¿qué has intentado, en qué parte tienes dudas?

Comment: No me imprime el resultado, por eso.

Comment: ya probaste con `echo $result["total"];` ?

Comment: Lo acabo de intentar aasi pero no me da.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola creo que podrias probar con algo como esto.

Agregando esta linea para tu consulta

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Esa linea devuelve un array asociativo (cadenas como índices) para los campos y es por eso que podemos acceder a ella mediante el nombre 'total' que es el alias que le pusiste en tu consulta.

```
<?php 
    $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','database');

     $sql="SELECT SUM(Cantidad) as total FROM ficha";
     $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
     echo $row['total'];

   ?>
```

Comment: !Muchas Gracias!